# Passing a variable to an iframe window in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Im a bit of a noob to jquery and js so ill try be as informative as I can.

I am using facebox on my page and a link which opens facebox which in turn loads an iframe inside calling a source page for the iframe window.

Loaded into the iframe then is a page which contains a form. The form validates via script thats attached to the parent window calling the iframe & facebox. The validating works but what i want to do is pass a variable back to the iframe window upon validation.

The form i refer to asks the user to create a new photo album which then appends to a select box once created as indicated here: (ill keep it brief)

var albumname = form.albumname.value;
$(""+albumname+"").appendTo('#als');
document.getElementById('albumname').value='Enter a name for a photo album';

Can anyone tell me how to pass this correctly to the iframe window?
Everything else works including the last line of code that resets the album name text input field.

Many thanks in advance,

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the contents of your iframe you can use a selector similar to this.

```
$("div", nameOfIframe.document)
```

What you need to remember is that your iframe need to be in the same domain as your main page, or else it won't work.

Comment: I tried this:

$("<option value='"+albumname+"' selected='selected'>"+albumname+"</option>").appendTo($("#als", "upframe".document)); 

Am i on the right track?

Thanks for replies

Comment: Well, if #als is a select and you change "upframe".document to upframe.document, you might be.

Comment: hmmmm didnt work, when facebox's modal window opens it loads iframe.php from a sub folder, this then references the iframe source page also located in the same folder. Might this be the problem do you think?

Comment: Got it working thanks Ole. Always nice to get help on these things, thanks again. Wayne